# Angular flexLayout components overlap

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-flex-layout

I thought it would be good to create a resume based on Angular 6. You could create separate components for each part of your resume. e.g one for your profile, one for your education, one for your portfolio etc. I build each one of these using Angular flexLayout. Individually they look fine but when I stack them in the app.component.html the text/ images overlap.

I have created a simple stackblitz to demonstrate this.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-wzzmnn?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 2):

You have declared in the child components fxLayout="column" and used the same in your parent. Just remove the declaration on the child components

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-4nkkyu?file=app/education/education.component.html

Comment: Many thanks. This also works. I can put the resume headers, About Me, Education in the app.component.html and use them as markers for the component selectors.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with the height of your components.

This is a very common CSS issue. See the flex layout as a float layout : the elements are getting out of the document flow to be placed, and they rely on width & height of their containers.

By fixing the height of the container, you fix the issue.

In your case, the container should take 100% of the height of its own container :

```
<div fxLayout="column" [style.height]="'100%'">
```

And you need to set the height of the containers of this container (don't get lost !)

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

This gives [the result you should be expecting](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-flex-layout-seed-sq3ysr?file=app%2Fapp.component.html) (I hope so anyway)

Comment: That is a huge help. I was really stuck on this. Now thanks to you I can move

Comment: I have just noticed that when I shrink the width to say iPhone 7 size then I get the merging problem again even though I am using Angular flexLayout.

Comment: I got it working using

<div fxLayout="column" [style.height]="'100%'">
    <app-aboutme fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="95%"></app-aboutme>
    <app-education fxFlex="50%" fxFlex.xs="5%"></app-education>
</div>

Comment: You can also declare it as `fxLayout="row wrap"` so that the components go to a new line instead of overlapping.

Comment: Don't understand. I am using fxLayout="column" so that the components can stack. How can I also use fxLayout="row wrap" ? Oh sorry yes you mean in the components themselves. Excellent. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, forgot you were in column mode, since you asked about width. You can use `wrap` to make the elements take a new line if they are not narrow enough to all fit on a single line. See it as the bootstrap equivalent of their grid system.

Comment: Could you please edit the stackblitz and show me what you mean. I can't make it stack properly when I make the window narrow as in a mobile device.

Comment: I am finding Angular flexLayout frustrating to use. Is there a better way to get elements to work responsively?

Comment: Once you get used to it it becomes very easy to use. You just have to get the grip on it. I suggest you use colored containers when you learn, so that you see how they behave throughout your application. About the blitz, I'm on phone so I'll do it tomorrow